# Newly Modified file , created and list huge files in CMD

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cmd, command-line, magento2

I have magento 2.2.6 website in aws server (EC2).I am connecting to that aws sever using ssh in cmd From my windows 10 computer . I have a directory (folder) named Var in aws server. Inside var folder there are so many files and sub folder .  Now i have the following question

1) I want to know the list of last modified files (or i want to get file modified after 2.00pm today )

2) I want to know the list of last created files (or i want to get file modified after 2.00pm today )

3) I want to list the files or folders that have size more than 1 gb

4) I want to know the folder size of one folder

Please help to solve this issue . I want cmd code . Actually i have [issue in my website](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313448/magento-2-2-6-disk-space-utilization-very-fast) . To  solve that i have to get the answer for these questions . Please help .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `du -sh` to get folder size. More examples are available [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/du-command-linux-examples/).
You can use 'ls -halt' to sort files by date or reverse it using `ls -haltr`, you your can read [this stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created) link on how to sort by date using various other ways.

You can use `find . -type f -size +1000M` to find files lager than 1GB, or if you want to limit it to the current folder you can use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1000M`. You can read [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/204564/how-can-i-find-files-that-are-bigger-smaller-than-x-bytes) on how to find files larger or smaller than.